# Overlay is blurry on Google Maps base layer but not OpenStreetMap with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2

As the title says, my layers will show up blurry on top of any of the Google Maps base layers, but not on top of OpenStreetMap. I am using OpenLayers 2.12.

See the screenshots attached below:

[image: GMAPS]

[image: OSM]

Comment: Looks like 2 different zoom levels and the line is thicker on the top one.  Is this a line or a polygon?  Overall looks "fine" to me on both.  And is the top one Google API on it's own, or Google via OpenLayers?

Comment: may be we need to see some code? and the site?

Comment: Further to Vadim's and iant's comments, can you also make the data available? At least a representative sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you get a chance to update your question, it *may* be that you are displaying a cached service in epsg 4326, and in the openlayers map with the projection set to 4326, then it appears fuzzy in google maps when being displayed in googles default spherical mercator projection.

Comment: So obvious it was difficult to notice. Definitely a mix up with projections. Fixed. Thank you.